# C++ - Inserting Linked list (A) into another Linked list (B) at position n

Tags: c++, linked-list

Example:
Linked List A:  1->2->3
Linked List B: 4->5->6

My task is to make a function, that passes List B into List A at any given position (n).
For instance: After "2" =     1->4->5->6->2->3 (output).

I wasn't really sure, how to do this, so I used:

// Function that finds a number in a list and gets an address of that node.

```
Node* List::find(int i)
{
for (start();!end();next())
        if(current->num==i) return current;
return NULL;
};
```

// Function, that puts freely desired number at position n in the list;

Example cin >> i;             // i = **6**;

1->2->**6**->desired number->...

```
Node* List::addAfter(int pos, int num)
{
 Node* p = NULL; i


 current = find(pos);


    if (current != NULL)
    {
        p = new Node(num);
        p->next = current->next;
        current->next = p;
    }

    if (last == current) last = p;

    current = p;

 return p;
}
```

Both things works, but only as:

```
 cout << "After which number?" << endl;
 cin >> i;  // **2**


l.addAfter(i, 1); // Before: 2->3->4    After: 2->1->3->4
l.print();
```

This works perfectly! But if I have two lists - l1 (2->3->4 and l2 6->7)
how can I put both together using this function?

Node* List::addAfter(int pos, **I HAVE TO PASS L2 VALUES HERE**)
How can I give this function l2 values as parameter? 
Is there maybe a better way, to do this? I'd appreciate any help.

---

WHOLE CODE:

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node
{
   public:
    int num;
    Node *next;
    Node (int n) { num = n; next = NULL; };
};

class List
{
protected:
    Node *first, *last;
public:
    Node *current;
public:
    List () { first = last = current = NULL; };
    void add_element (int n); 
    void delete_element ();  
    void print(); // Izdrukā sarakstu

    bool is_empty () { return (first == NULL); };
    void start () { current = first; };
    bool end () { return (current == NULL); };
    void next(){if (!end())current = current -> next;};

    Node* find(int i);  
    Node* addAfter(int i, List * l2); 
    ~List();  



};








int main()
{
 List l, l2;
 int k, i;
 cout << "Type number: (0,to stop):\n";
 cin >> k;
 while (k!=0)
 {
 l.add_element (k);
 cout << "Type number: (0, to stop):\n";  
 cin >> k;
 };
 cout << endl;

 cout << "Type 2nd list numbers: (0,to stop):\n";
 cin >> k;
 while (k!=0)
 {
 l2.add_element (k);
 cout << "Type 2nd list numbers: (0,to stop):\n";   
 cin >> k;
 };
 cout << endl;


 l.print();
 l2.print();

 cout << "After which element do you want to insert second list?" << endl;
 cin >> i;


l.addAfter(i, l2); // GETTING ERROR HERE.
l.print();




return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your example looked like BEFORE 2 and not After right?

Comment: @Maartin1996  In C/C++ poistions usually start from 0.

Comment: `How can I give this function l2 values as parameter?` Well, you simply pass `List *l2` instead of `int num`. And then you change pointers of i-th node to begining of `l2` and change the end of `l2` to (i+1)-th node. Is this a homework? It seems that you are having issues with very basic stuff.

Comment: You "pass `l2` values" by passing `l2`. Inside the function, you traverse `l2` and add its values to the result.

Comment: @freakish Can u show me that in code, please? I just started learning linked lists, and it's pain in ass for me, haha. I edited topic, now you can see whole code also (at the end).

Comment: try `Node* List::addAfter(int pos, Node *list)`

Answer (score 0):

simplest and easiest form is to pour out both stacks into an array

```
const int size = stackA.size() + stackB.size();
const stackASize = stackA.size();
const stackBSize = stackB.size();
int arrayOfStackA [size];

int arrayOfStackB [stackBSize];


//Pop StackA into ArrayA

for(int i=stackASize-1; i>0; i++)

{
    arrayOfStackA[i] = stackA.pop();

}


//Pop StackB into ArrayB

for(int i=stackBSize-1; i>=0; i++)
{
     arrayOfStackB[i] = stackB.pop();
}
```

Now find the index where you want to insert the data in array A.
In your case you want to enter stack b after 1 which in case of array is the index:1

```
int count = 0
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    if(i<requiredIndexNumber){
            //do nothing
    }
    else if(i>=requiredIndexNumber && count!=stackBSize){
            int temp = arrayOfStackA[i];
            arrayOfStackA[i] = arrayOfStackB[count++];
            arrayOfStackA[stackASize+i] = temp;
    }
}
```

This is the most easiest from of popping one stack into an other at any index

Comment: I can't use pop methods ect. Check my topics end part, there's a whole code for clearer picture.

Comment: You cannot add something in the middle of stack its against the concept of stack. If you do so then that wouldn't be a stack anymore it will become either a (*LinedList or simple Array what ever method you are using.)

Comment: Well, I need some solution including Linked List, because that was my task. Do you have any ideas that could help me, if u check my current code? I'm pretty sure my afterAdd function is pretty messed up.